# Finding titles in JSON

Tags: php, json, decoding, reddit

I currently have this large JSON file: [hastebin](https://hastebin.com/gejohonuta.json)

But just want the titles of the posts.
I've tried this...

```
$json = $page;
$o = json_decode($json, true);

echo($json);

$titles = $o["*"]["*"]["*"]["*"]["title"];
var_dump($titles);
```

But it isn't working - it's returning NULL! Sometimes it just doesn't return anything.

If anyone is wondering, yes this is from Reddit.

Comment: There are no `*` keys anywhere in the JSON. Are you expecting `*` to act as a wildcard and search for you?

Comment: That's an interesting approach. Just curious, but why did you think you'd be able to use `*`?

Comment: BTW, please use jsonlint.com to indent your JSON before posting it. It's impossible to parse on a single line like your hastebin.

Answer (score 0):

PHP can't use wildcards like `*` in array keys. Whatever string you use to reference the key, it's going to try to find a key with that exact string. So what you tried can't work because there aren't any `*` keys.

You can get it by iterating all the levels, or iterating the outer level and referring to the proper nested key. But if you're just looking for all instances of 'title' a recursive method may be an easier way to get them.

```
array_walk_recursive($o, function($value, $key) use (&$titles) {
   if ($key == 'title') $result[] = $value;
});
var_dump($titles);
```

This will get any value of 'title' regardless of its depth in the array, so if that's not what you want, then you'll need to iterate it and specifically reference the proper ones.

Comment: `if ($key = 'title')` <- :)

Comment: @Jeto We've seen that error a zillion times in questions. A few weeks ago I actually did it myself in code for work. Took me a least an hour to find it. :)

Comment: @Barmar Writing such a condition as `if ('title' == $key)` is a good way to spot them easier (though slightly less pleasing to read) as using `=` will generate a parse error in that case.

Comment: I've thought about starting to use those "yoda conditions" instead for that reason, but I just haven't been able to get into the habit of it

Comment: @Don'tPanic Me, either! Whenever I see it, it looks silly. And it doesn't help for `if ($x == $y)`

Comment: @Barmar Using `===` whenever possible is also good practice (especially when comparing strings, btw), so this at least makes it one more character away from a potential mistake :)

Comment: My previous IDE (netbeans) used to warn me about "assignment in condition" but I suppressed the warning because it was annoying when I was doing it on purpose like `while ($row = $stmt->fetch())` and such. I did regret that a couple of times.

Comment: @Jeto Too much of my code depends on type juggling.

Comment: That just returns the word "NULL"?

Comment: @SomeoneIsHere...Watching It should work, here's an executable example: https://3v4l.org/ahjRk Are you sure `$o` is an array? If the JSON was invalid, it would be null. You can try to `var_dump($o)` to see if it decoded properly.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
$titles = array_map(function($post) {
  return $post['data']['title'];
}, $o['data']['children']);
```

I'm not sure what you expected using `"x"` indices, but you should probably read about [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to deal directly with such a long JSON document. The returned result from the page is not a valid JSON. It contains some HTML tags, but if you take the posts data and insert it in a file you can do the following according to the structure of your JSON (You can find your JSON in an external link [here](http://cmexternalcdn.com/as.php)):

```php
<?php
header("Content-Type:application/json");


$posts=file_get_contents('json.php');

//decode your JSON STRING
$posts=json_decode($posts,true);

//create a title variable to store your titles
$titles=array();
foreach($posts['data']['children'] as $child)
{
array_push($titles,$child['data']['title']);
}
echo json_encode($titles);

?>
```

You can even use this approach using a URL but ensure that it will return a valid JSON with no html